# RadGridView change Row color after cell CheckBox checked/unchecked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a simple RadGridView, inside the first cell i have `Checkbox` in which I want to change the color of my row if this `Checkbox` is checked state and return to the original color if this `Checkbox` is in unchecked state.

Currently this is what i have try and this paint my Row when my `Checkbox` is checked but how can i change to the original color when my `Checkbox` is uncheckd ?

```
        private void radGridView1_RowFormatting(object sender, RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.RowElement.RowInfo.Cells["Select"].Value == true)
        {
            e.RowElement.DrawFill = true;
            e.RowElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
            e.RowElement.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
        }
        else
        {
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.BackColorProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.GradientStyleProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
            e.RowElement.ResetValue(LightVisualElement.DrawFillProperty, ValueResetFlags.Local);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx Please refer this.

Comment: Where i need to look ? (i am new developer...)

Comment: refer the link and see the code in example under that link page

Comment: Another link: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-selecting-row-with-click-client-side.html

Comment: This is also to Winforms ?

Comment: Its my mistake. I thought its webforms. Anyways you can look into http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-formatting-rows.html

Comment: Please see my update, the current function do what i want but if i press on checkbox cell and checked it draw this cell only after another cell is checked and same behavior while unchecked

Comment: Please Assign Cell id or name like this Cells["BMP"].Value as mentioned in the example.

Comment: This is what i did and it still happen

Comment: you did exactly what mentioned in the example? if yes then update your code.

Comment: RowFormatting event is fired when you click on select for the first time?

Comment: Yes but in the first time when the checkbox is unchecked it goes into the else, the value property is false although this chckbox unchecked

Comment: If you want to assign different color when checkbox is checked meaning the value is true I think you have to use it in another event when you bind grid. Because the one you are using will only change the color if the value is true. So if the checkbox's value is 'True' then it will not change the row color.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is correct and it should change the color of the rows with checked first cell. However, there is one thing to note. The editor of the check box cell is permanent editor, and its value will be submitted to the cell, only after you change the current row in the grid. If this does not work for you, there is an easy way to submit the value immediately upon changing the check box state. Here you can find out how to do it: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-editors-howto-checkboxeditor-submit-value-change.html